# ignore scanner input while testing junit

Tags: java, junit

How do I ignore the sysout statement while testing the following method?

```
public int inputBoardSize() {
    System.out.print("Enter the number of grids you want to play with:");
    while (flag) {
        try {
            boardSize = validateBoardSize(Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine()));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("Please enter a number");
        }
    }
    printBoard(boardSize);
    return boardSize;
}
```

So when I am testing this method, I get a prompt asking me to enter the number of grids. How do I solve this?

Comment: What do you need to ignore exactly?

Comment: Maybe create the Scanner instance as a `Mock` object and define the behavior of `scan.nextLine()` by yourself. See [link](http://site.mockito.org/) for that. By doing it, you can check as many inputs as you want. You can also create another testing method for your logic, and use relevant inputs instead of using the scanner.

Comment: @Zabuza I want to test the NumberFormatException in the inputBoardSize method

Comment: @Vishakha You don't test the internal behavior of a method. You only test the behavior it has from the outside (the documentation). The method consumes the exception, it won't throw it so you can't test it. The method will continue until the given value is valid, I don't see how you can test that. You should break it into several pieces and test them, like the `validateBoardSize` method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **mock** the resource. Therefore create a wrapping interface like

```
public interface LineProvider {
    String nextLine();
}
```

and implementing classes, first the class that you will use in the actual program:

```
public class UserInput implements LineProvider {
    private Scanner mScanner;

    public UserInput(Scanner scanner) {
        mScanner = scanner;
    }

    @Override
    public String nextLine() {
        return mScanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

And then your **mock** that you will use for tests:

```
public class UserInputMock implements LineProvider {
    private String mLineToReturn;

    public UserInputMock(String initialLine) {
        mLineToReturn = initialLine;
    }

    public void setLineToReturn(String lineToReturn) {
        mLineToReturn = lineToReturn;
    }

    @Override
    public String nextLine() {
        return mLineToReturn;
    }
}
```

---

Now let your method accept the resource as parameter:

```
public int inputBoardSize(LineProvider provider) {
    ...
    boardSize = validateBoardSize(Integer.parseInt(provider.nextLine()));
    ...
}
```

---

And in your main program you use an `UserInput` like

```
UserInput userInput = new UserInput(scan);
...
inputBoardSize(userInput);
```

whereas in your test you use the mock:

```
UserInputMock mock = new UserInputMock("hello world");
inputBoardSize(mock); // Not valid

mock.setLineToReturn("5");
inputBoardSize(mock); // Valid
```

Note that there are frameworks to make stuff like that easier.

Comment: Using Mockito will be much more straightforward, but nice design :)

Comment: Yup, if one really wants to mock a lot one should definitely consider getting some framework.